# Jest test.each with object property in name

Tags: jestjs, parameterized-unit-test

I have a parameterized test:

```
test.each([myObjWithMyPropertyTrue, myObjWithMyPropertyFalse])
  ('should do something when %o', (myObj) => {
```

but instead of printing the entire object with %o, I want to print the value of property MyObj.myProperty

does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jest .each name access object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800074/jest-each-name-access-object-key)

Comment: @segFault yes the tagged template literal form of describe.each solves this, thanks :)